# React(next.js) is giving me "handleSubmit is not defined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I used react Class components but know I want to use functions.
And I have a problem because it keeps telling me that handleSubmit is not defined. BUT not in call but like in the beginning of function.

This was correct.

```
 class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {
 ........
      handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
          if (!err) {
            console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
          }
        });
      };
............
render() {
..........
return{
........
}}
```

And i changed it to this

```
   const RegistrationForm = () => {
  ..........
    handleSubmit = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
    axioswal
      .post('/api/users', {
        firstname,
        secondname,
        email,
        password,
      })
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.status === 'ok') {
          dispatch({ type: 'fetch' });
          redirectTo('/');
        }
          });
      };
  .....
  return {
  ......
  }
```

And I am calling it here

```
 return (
        <Form {...formItemLayout} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Item
          label={
```

But I don't know what to do to make it work.
I will be thankful for any help.

Comment: In hooks version you have to call handleSubmit without this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In functional components you don't define functions inside the component as properties, so you have to use `const`.

So your code would look like this:

```
const RegistrationForm = props => {
  ........

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      }
    });
  };

  ..........

  return .........
}}
```

And then in your return statement you wouldn't use `this.handleSubmit`, just `handleSubmit`. Like this:

```
return (
  <Form {...formItemLayout} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Form.Item
      label={
```

Also, don't use `this.props` when referencing props. The props get passed to your component as function arguments.

Answer (score 1):

In Functional component, you don't need to put **"this"** keyword. Just call the handleSubmit as it is.

```
<Form {...formItemLayout} onSubmit={handleSubmit}></Form>
```

Answer (score 1):

put a const in front of your method definition(handleSubmit).

```
class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {
 ........
      const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
          if (!err) {
            console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
          }
        });
      };
............
render() {
..........
return{
........
}}
```

and of course no need to put this in calling method if you've used function component.